# how to loop through ann array with curl function?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I can't loop through an array, stil get Curl error "3"
i have checked and inside array are all links I wanted to get.

function to make a get request

```
 <?php
 function geturl($url){
 $starttime = microtime(TRUE);
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) 
                                      Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
 [
'https://betsapi.com/',
'authority: betsapi.com',
'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
 
'accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,
 application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' ,
'sec-fetch-mode: navigate',
'sec-fetch-user: ?1',
'sec-fetch-dest: document',
//'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Microsoft Edge";v="98"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"',
'referer: https://betsapi.com/',
'accept-language: pl,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7',
  ]);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

here i check errors and request time

```
 if(curl_errno($ch))
 {
  echo "Curl error no: ". curl_errno($ch);
  exit;
 }

  curl_close($ch);

  $endtime = microtime(TRUE);
  echo "Request time"." ". $endtime - $starttime."\n";
   return $response;
  }
```

function to load html

```
   function simplehtml($item){
   include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
   $html = new simple_html_dom();
   $html->load($item);
    return $html;
   }
```

when i call for the first time the geturl function and simplehtml function it works and puts all links into array

```
    $starturl= geturl('https://betsapi.com/cin/soccer');
    $starturlhtml= simplehtml($starturl);

    foreach($starturlhtml->find("tr[class='c_1'] td[class='text-center'] a")as $url){
    $url="https://betsapi.com".$url->href."\n";
    $urlarray[]=$url;

    }
```

here i call it in loop and i get Curl error 3

```
    foreach($urlarray as $urls){
     $urlss= geturl($urls);
     $urlshtml=simplehtml($urlss);
     foreach($urlshtml->find("div[class='col-md-6 text-center'] p b")as $stadium){
      echo $stadium;
      sleep(2);
     }
     }
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Maybe it could help to not append a `\n` to the URLs you try to request?

Comment: Nico Haase thank you so much,  i removed "\n" and it works!!